# Split matrix into SubMatrixes of Leading Coefficients

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working with MATLAB_R2016a, and am currently trying to find the right matrix fraction description of a MIMO system. Suppose I have a matrix of the form:

```
[s^2+3s+1, s+1, s^3+2s; s^3+3, s^2-6, s-5];
```

Is there a simple way to generate submatrixes of coefficients for each degree of s? Like so:

```
[0, 0, 1; 1, 0, 0] s^3 + [0, 0, 0 ; 0, 1, 0] s^2 + [3, 1, 2; 0, 0, 1] s + [1,1,0;3,-6,-5];
```

I figure it can be done with a loop and extracting the degree of each polynomial element, but wanted to know if people had found easier work-arounds?

Comment: Check this: https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/coeffs.html. I don't have the necessary toolbox to test it but if you can enter the entire polynomial into the coeff() function, you'll get sub-matrices for each of them. You can then create a matrix per polynomial element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use symbolic toolbox to work on polynomials. So, as [@10a commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557112/split-matrix-into-submatrixes-of-leading-coefficients/46559197#comment80070643_46557112) you can use `coeffs` function.
You just need to made some workaround to get final result.

For arbitrary polynomials you can use the next code:

```
syms x

% find all coefficients for each polynomial. Results are of different sizes!
% because of different degrees of polinomils
coef = arrayfun( @(y) coeffs(y, 'All') , [2*x^2 + 3*x + 5, x^2+3; x^3, x + 7] ,...
                'UniformOutput' , false)

% find max degree
max_size = cellfun( @(x) size(x,2), coef)
max_size = max(max_size(:))

% and finally fill with zeros all surplus places in arrays to get unified size 
result = cellfun( @(x) [zeros(1, max_size - size(x,2)) x], coef, 'UniformOutput', false)
```